# How to create a Go regexp object using syntax.Literal?

Tags: regex, go

The Go [regexp](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp) package uses [re2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), which supports these four flags:

```
i   case-insensitive (default false)
m   multi-line mode: ^ and $ match begin/end line in addition to begin/end text (default false)
s   let . match \n (default false)
U   ungreedy: swap meaning of x* and x*?, x+ and x+?, etc (default false)
```

The [syntax package](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax#Flags) has at least one additional flag:

```
Literal // treat pattern as literal string
```

This flag would seem to correspond to the [xpath regex 'q' flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#flags). I could use this! However, I can't figure out how to compile a regex with `syntax.Literal`, only an AST using `syntax.Parse` — and I see no way to compile the AST (the [`compile` method](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.1:src/regexp/regexp.go;l=171) is private)

Is there some way to create `regexp.Regexp` objects with other flags from the `syntax` package that aren't supported by `regexp.Compile` or `regexp.CompilePOSIX`?

Or would I just need to run a pattern through `QuoteMeta` before handing it off to `Compile`?

Comment: If you mean to use some text as plain text in the regular expression (so that `(` is searched for as an open parenthesis), then `QuoteMeta` is the right choice.

Comment: how about syntax.Parse()?

Comment: I'm using `syntax.Parse()` (and `syntax.Compile()`) to make sure it compiles, yes, but how do I produce a `regexp.Regexp` that I can actually execute?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That matches the description of the xpath regex 'q' flag: “q: if present, all characters in the regular expression are treated as representing themselves, not as metacharacters.” Just annoying not to have a matching option to use; instead I'll have to translate the other flags from xpath to regex flags, but then if there is qu also pre-process the pattern with `QuoteMeta` before compiling it. Do-able, but would be easier of `syntax.Literal` could be set by a `(?q)` flag, or else one could compile a Regex from the syntax AST.

Comment: You can't expect different regex libraries to have the same features, they are created by different people, and some of them would say what you want to do is not what they would have done - I guess :)

Comment: I don't expect them to have the same features. There is no `/x` flag either, and that's fine. What I do expect is when the feature exists for there to be some way to use it. Perhaps there is and I can't figure it out, or perhaps it doesn't do what I think it does. Either way I learn something.